# create week-only calendar in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a calendar containing weeks, month and year only using DAX. I'm getting the start week and end week from a table called Messaging. When I use calendar, it generates dates as well, I had to work around this by selecting the distinct values from the week column in the table generated with calendar, the code is as follows

```
CalendarTable = 
var Calendartemporay =    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CALENDAR ( MIN ( Messaging[week] ), MAX ( Messaging[week] ) ),
        "Monday", [Date] - WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ),
        "month", FORMAT([Date],"mmmmm")
    )

var Weekonly = SELECTCOLUMNS(Calendartemporay, 
"Week", [Monday])
var unique_weeks = DISTINCT(Weekonly)
var month_temporary = Format(unique_weeks,"mmmm")

return month_temporary
```

However, I get the message

```
The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression.
```

How can I fix this and get a table with the unique weeks, their months and year ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS(

    CALENDAR(DATE(2019, 1, 1), DATE(2025, 12, 31)),
    "Week Number", WEEKNUM([Date]),
    "Month Year", FORMAT([Date], "MMM yyyy")
```

)

Comment: You will also need to remove any unnecessary columns from the calendar table, such as the "Date" column if it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, however, I need unique Week values, since that's my date granularity in the Messaging table. the column date is not required.